# How to kill a process that calls execv?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, kill, exec

A process that calls [`execv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) is not dying, by, what looks like, design.

Example borrowed from [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/execv.htm):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
   pid_t pid;
   char *const parmList[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l", "/u/userid/dirname", NULL};

   if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
      perror("fork error");
   else if (pid == 0) {
      execv("/bin/ls", parmList);
      printf("Return not expected. Must be an execv error.n");
   }
}
```

If I call that executable `foo`, how can I kill foo after it starts?  My only option seems to capture the parent process ID and then kill that.

```
foo &
echo $! > /path/to/foo_pid
kill /path/to/foo_pid
```

But I don't have a way to capture the PID of the parent process.

Comment: Why can't you kill the process using its PID?

Comment: Have you tried `kill -9` with the process PID?